# Erro ao tentar converter data portuguesa em datetime

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Estou com um problema e não estou a encontrar nenhuma solução para o corrigir.
Tenho uma data neste formato: Quarta-feira, 30 Abril, 2014
e quero guardar esta data no banco de dados no tipo `datetime`.

Então estou a tentar fazer a conversão para o tipo `datetime`, mas estou com um problema:

**Se a data estiver em ingês**: `Wednesday, 30 April, 2014` então  meu `echo` funciona, e mostra a data em date time.

**Se a data estiver em português:** `Quarta-feira, 30 Abril, 2014` o `echo` já não funciona e tenho este erro: `Call to a member function format() on a non-object`.

Estou a fazer a conversão com a class DateTime::

```
$data= DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', 'Quarta-feira, 30 Abril, 2014');
echo $data->format('Y-m-d');
```

Alguém já teve este problema e sabe como posso resolver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function dataPT($data){
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $data);
        $day    = $date->format("l");
        $daynum = $date->format("j");
        $month  = $date->format("F");
        $year   = $date->format("Y");

        switch($day)
        {
            case "Monday":    $day = "Segunda-Feira";  break;
            case "Tuesday":   $day = "Terça-Feira"; break;
            case "Wednesday": $day = "Quarta-Feira";  break;
            case "Thursday":  $day = "Quinta-Feira"; break;
            case "Friday":    $day = "Sexta-Feira";  break;
            case "Saturday":  $day = "Sábado";  break;
            case "Sunday":    $day = "Domingo";  break;
            default:          $day = "Unknown"; break;
        }

        switch($month)
        {
            case "January":   $month = "Janeiro";    break;
            case "February":  $month = "Fevereiro";   break;
            case "March":     $month = "Março";     break;
            case "April":     $month = "Abril";     break;
            case "May":       $month = "Maio";       break;
            case "June":      $month = "Junho";      break;
            case "July":      $month = "Julho";      break;
            case "August":    $month = "Agosto";    break;
            case "September": $month = "Setembro"; break;
            case "October":   $month = "Outubro";   break;
            case "November":  $month = "Novembro";  break;
            case "December":  $month = "Dezembro";  break;
            default:          $month = "Unknown";   break;
        }

    echo $daynum . " de " . $month . " de " . $year;
}
```

Aqui você recebe as datas em inglês e altera para português, você pode alterar a função para português para inglês e realizar a conversão antes de executar a função.

Comment: Muito obrigado, finalmente problema resolvido!! :)

Comment: Afinal, olhei para o código e parecia ser o que andava à procura, mas agora que testei, estou a ter o mesmo erro!