# Função data em Português

Tags: php, mysql, data

Tenho esse codigo

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed  lista-clientes table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>
                 <center>IP Address</center>
              </th>
              <th>
                 <center>Banned By</center>
              </th>
              <th>
                 <center>Reason</center>
              </th>
              <th>
                 <center>Banned On</center>
              </th>
              <th>
                 <center>Banned Until</center>
              </th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <?php 
           date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
           while($row = $retval->fetch_assoc()) { 
              if($row['banner'] == null) {
                 $row['banner'] = 'Console';
              }
              // <<-----------------Ban Date Converter------------>> //
              $timeEpoch = $row['time'];
              $timeConvert = $timeEpoch / 1000;
              $timeResult = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $timeConvert);
              // <<-----------------Expiration Time Converter------------>> //
              $expiresEpoch = $row['expires'];
              $expiresConvert = $expiresEpoch / 1000;
              $expiresResult = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $expiresConvert);
              ?>
           <tr>
              <td>
                 <?php
                    $ip = $row['ip'];

                    $array = explode(".", $ip);
                    $numbers = $array[0] . "." . $array[1] . "." . $array[2];
                    $numbers .= ".";

                    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($array[3]); $i++) {
                      $numbers .= "*";
                    }

                    echo $numbers;
                    ?>
              </td>
              <td><?php echo $row['banner'];?></td>
              <td style="width: 30%;"><?php echo $row['reason'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $timeResult;?></td>
              <td><?php if($row['expires'] == 0) {
                 echo 'ETERNO';
                 } else {
                 echo $expiresResult; }?></td>
           </tr>
           <?php }
              $conn->close();
              echo "</tbody></table>";
              ?>
```

Porem quero deixar a data, horários etc... Em Português porem não estou conseguindo...
So esta ficando em inglês. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer a função date() formatar uma data em português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%c3%aas), [Data em português (pt-br)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183518/)

Comment: @wmsouza, eu ja visualizei isso porem não estou conseguindo !!!
Se eu perguntei aqui e porque eu não sei mesmo!

Comment: Veja a documentação, [Funções de Data/Hora](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php).

Comment: @wmsouza também nao consegui implementar no meu codigo !!
Voce poderia me ajudar arrumar ele ? Para ficar pt/br

Comment: Qual o valor da coluna `time` no banco de dados ?

Comment: [Erro ao tentar converter data portuguesa em datetime](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14430), mas perguntas sobre data no *PHP* veja essa [pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20data%20em%20português) ... Então de onde vem `$row['time']` ??

Comment: @wmsouza Nao tem coluna time

Comment: Da uma olhada ! Editei com o código completo.
http://prntscr.com/ih5kpy

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar as datas com localização em *"pt-BR" (Brasil)* ou *"pt-PT" (Portugal)*, são necessárias a utilização de duas funções: [**setlocale**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php) e [**strftime**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php).

A diferença entre `date` e `strftime` (além dos parâmetros), é que `strftime` trabalha com a localização indicada, enquanto `date` ignora esses valores.

Na função `setlocale`, nós podemos decidir se queremos aplicar a localização em todos os campos ou apenas data, dinheiro, tempo etc. Para aplicar somente com datas, utilize `setlocale(LC_TIME, "<Idioma>");`

```
<?php

/* Localização */
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt-BR");

/* Ignora a localização */
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL;

/* Aplica a data com localização */
echo strftime("%B %d, %G, %I:%M %p");
```

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt-BR");

while($row = $retval->fetch_assoc()) { 
    if($row['banner'] == null) {
    $row['banner'] = 'Console';
}

// <<-----------------Ban Date Converter------------>> //
$timeEpoch = $row['time'];
$timeConvert = $timeEpoch / 1000;
$timeResult = strftime("%B %d, %G, %I:%M %p", $timeConvert);

// <<-----------------Expiration Time Converter------------>> //
$expiresEpoch = $row['expires'];
$expiresConvert = $expiresEpoch / 1000;
$expiresResult =  strftime("%B %d, %G, %I:%M %p", $expiresConvert);
?>
```

> Para saber outros parâmetros da função `stftime`, basta acessar a [**documentação**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php)

Comment: Tentei e nao consegui... Não aparece nada quando ponho esse codigo

Comment: @zlDeath código atualizado

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ihhggd continua não aparecendo nada...

Comment: @zlDeath se possível posta seu código atualizado no [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) e posta o link aqui

Comment: https://hastebin.com/araluruvuw.xml

Comment: conseguiu ver ?

Comment: Verifique se `strftime` está retornando `false`. Caso esteja, é necessário modificar os parâmetros como `%I`, `%M` etc.  Verifique o valor de `$time` também e teste com o exemplo `var_dump(strftime("%A", 1519061884014 / 1000));`

Comment: Poderia editar no meu codigo e me mandar no hastebin ?

Comment: @zlDeath é complicado pois fico sem saber o retorno do SQL e algumas opções do `setlocale` muda a depender do servidor (windows e linux), também é necessário verificar na documentação. Por exemplo: Esse código funciona para mim: https://imgur.com/a/aDXpA

Comment: Mas nao poderia tentar so arrumar ? Mas acho que esteja retornando false pq nao aparece nada